# How does fetching a UI Image from firebase differ from fetching a UI Label in .text, and what are potential problems that arise from image fetches?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I have successfully fetched a UI label and displayed it, but am not sure how to fetch the Image.

I tried to copy paste the same framework for the image but it said you can't use String for an image in this form:

```
let x = y?["PhotoPost"]
```

---

```
////Here is what I have for the label: 

public  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

    let person: Userx = people[indexPath.row]

    cell.lblName.text = person.Education

    table.dataSource = self
    table.delegate = self

    return cell

}

databaseRef.observe(DataEventType.value,  with: {snapshot in

    if snapshot.childrenCount>0{


        self.people.removeAll()

        for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let peopleObject = people.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            let peopleEducation = peopleObject?["Education"]
            let peoplePhotoPosts = peopleObject?["PhotoPosts"]
            let peopl = Userx(Education: peopleEducation as! String?, PhotoPosts: peoplePhotoPosts as AnyObject)
                self.people.append(peopl)

        }
        self.table.reloadData()


    }

})
```

////Here is prelim code I have for the posing of picture

```
import SDWebImage.  

///installed in pod already

cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "il_570xN.1325825023_m2nl")

    if let PhotoPosts = person.PhotoPosts {
        let url = URL(string: PhotoPosts)
        cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
            return


        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }

    }).resume()

    }

    return cell

}
```

I also have the problem of PhotoPosts apparently being set to Dictionary and not String. I am not sure where it would be set as dictionary because in this file and the one with its class, it is all string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- This should be in `viewDidLoad`

```
table.dataSource = self
table.delegate = self
```

2- Cast like

```
let peopleObject = people.value as! [String: Any]
let peopleEducation = peopleObject?["Education"] as! String
let peoplePhotoPosts = peopleObject?["PhotoPosts"]  as! [String:Any]
print(peoplePhotoPosts)
```

3- Use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) to display remote images

---

This

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("people")
```

is a general url that will return the same content for every user in your app , instead you need this dataBase structure

```
> People
  > Uid
    >Education:""
    > so on
```

Then use

```
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("people/\(userID)")
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the SDWebImage documentation still current? The pod file install instruction is for iOS 8.

Comment: yes it supports swift 5 ignore that old ios 8 line you see

Comment: That part works. Thanks! I changed PhotoPosts to String here and in the class where it is init. However, this caused in error: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT in line                 let peoplePhotoPosts = peopleObject?["PhotoPosts"] as! String. The consul says ] Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x10d271c30) to 'NSString' (0x10c3404a8). Do you know why this would be?

Comment: your `peoplePhotoPosts` is a `Dictionary ` not `String` see edit........

Comment: Thanks. That fixes it but causes an error upstream: Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type 'String' That line is: let url = URL(string: PhotoPosts). Do you know why that is? I never recall setting anything to dictionary. I will update the new code I have for the Photo posting in the question.

Comment: Update. I decided to investigate why it was giving dictionary vs string as [String:Any] was not working. I figured out it was because a few users in the database were still in an older data format. I deleted them and it fixed the issue. Only remaining problem is the code doesn't work 100%; it only pulls up one user's image. Same user no matter who logs in. Very weird.

Comment: how you set `databaseRef`

Comment: let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("people");

Comment: It comes just before the databaseRef.observe(DataEventType.value,  with: {snapshot in line

Comment: Found below in consul message. Not sure what it means but am digging. 
2019-06-20 23:58:33.149463+0200 WestPluto1[8085:530368] Task <C1F80284-8E84-406E-BF15-3D537135C9D3>.<4> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https................

Comment: Thanks. My database looks exactly like you mentioned in the answer. You're logic makes perfect sense because currently my code goes from people directly to the child Education, skipping the Uid. However, for some reason it does work perfectly for all the child references other than photos. Using the (userID) in the child like you mentioned had the effect of making the snapshot only that current users, not all of them.